# If $\delta(G) \ge (n-1)/2$, then $\lambda(G) = \delta(G)$

Tags: graph-theory

How would I go about proving the above statement? I know that since $\delta(G) \ge (n-1)/2$, $G$ must be connected. Also, by a previous theorem, $\lambda(G) \le \delta(G)$.

I'm not sure how to show that $\lambda(G)$ cannot be less than $\delta(G)$.

Note: $\delta(G)$ = minimum degree of the graph. $\lambda(G)$ = minimum edge-connectivity of the graph.